# data driven curve - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, twitter-bootstrap, statistics, curve

I have several sets of data that I want to fit but not all of them look the same (some look like a Gaussian with one peak, some like two Gaussians with 2 peaks or Lorentzians). I wanted to try this method
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31562-data-driven-fitting-with-matlab/content/fitit.m
but the program given is not complete so I can not use it (there is no line that defines 'train' and 'test'). I am writing it so that it suits and works for my data (based on the code that it is given and the demo). I was able to find the best fit but I am also trying to use the bootstrap technique in order to find the confidence intervals. My data is xdata and ydata and they are sorted and the duplicates have been removed before I use them in my program.

```
cpart=cvpartition(size(xdata,1),'k',10); 
tr_x=xdata(training(cpart,1));
tr_y=ydata(training(cpart,1));
tst_x=xdata(test(cpart,1));
tst_y=ydata(test(cpart,1));

all_span=linspace(0.01,0.99,99);
s=zeros(length(all_span);
for k=1:length(all_span)
f = @(tr_x,tr_y,tst_x,tst_y)  norm(tst_y mylowess (tr_x, tr_y, tst_x,  all_span (k)))^2
s(k) = sum(crossval(f,datax,datay,'partition',cpart));
end

 [~,mj]=min(s);
 n_span=all_span(mj);%n_span is the optimal span


function ys=mylowess(x1,y1,xs,span)
ys1 = smooth(x1,y1,span,'loess');
ys = interp1(x1,ys1,xs,'linear',NaN);
if any(isnan(ys))
   ys(xs<x1(1)) = ys1(1);
   ys(xs>x1(end)) = ys1(end);
end
```

So up to this point I understand the program and I have managed to find the optimal span. I want to find the confidence intervals but so far I was not able to make it work.

When I type:

```
   NB=length(xdata);
   f=@(xdata,ydata) mylowess(xdata,ydata,xdata,n_span);
   yboot2 = bootstrp(NB,f,xdata,ydata)';
```

I get the following error

Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.

Error in interp1 (line 186)
        F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);

Error in mylowess (line 26)
ysmooth=interp1(xdata,ysmooth1,xinput,'linear',NaN);

As I said before there are no duplicates in xdata and I have already sorted xdata before I used them in the program. Can anyone see the mistake I am making? Or is there an easier way to get the confidence intervals?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Bootstrap will produce duplicates and change the order. You could go for jackknive which will not produce duplicates - still you might need to sort again.

Comment: i am not familiar with this technique, can you give me an example?

Comment: The syntax is nearly the same: http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/jackknife.html